# Speed up RubyMine 4.5 in Ubuntu

Tags: rubymine

I like RubyMine, I'm using only it. But the only thing that makes me be worried is that a performance of RubyMine. It takes too much RAM. So I want to turn off unnecessary functionality to speed up it.

What would you suggest me?

Comment: See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1144 and http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1232. Disabling plug-in you don't use may also help a bit.

Comment: I'm on 64x Ubuntu. Is it possible to start RubyMine in 32x mode?

Comment: Just install and run under 32bit JDK.

Answer (score 0):

By reading this post below my Rubymine it not easy to freeze:)

[Set/Increase Memory Available In Rubymine](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/uncategorized/setincrease-memory-available-in-rubymine/)

Comment: I just start using Sublime Text2.